# Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll in Visual Studio 2015 installation?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-sdk

I followed instructions in article about [supporting multiple versions of Visual Studio in developing checkin policies](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/creating-custom-check-in-policy-pack.html). Now, where can I find :

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
```

For Team Foundation Server 2015 (version 14) under my VS2015 installation? (Or in NuGet?)

There is nothing like that in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I updated the blog post.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These have [been moved into a Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/).

They're also stored under the "CommonExtensions" folder of your Visual Studio installation, but these are not meant to be referenced anymore, that's what the NuGet package is for.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

Comment: I would obviously prefer to use the package, but build fails after replacing the old library with this package as there is no namespace or type under the name ``Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl``. Also, ``https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client%28v=vs.120%29.aspx`` does not provide documentation for the namespace for the current version of VS. Hm. It seems like support for this stuff was discontinued?

Comment: Updated the link to reference the ExtendedClient package which has the dll's you're looking for.I'm not playing a jedi mind trick on ya ;)!

Comment: Microsoft, thank you for adding 49 new references after installing that package.... HATE YOU!

Comment: @jessehouwing:  Thanks, we have upgraded to the NuGet package as we hoped it is a better dependency management mechanism than referencing directly from the Team Explorer folder.  However, I am somewhat floored by the huge number of references I have now got in my project.

Comment: Hahaha the 72 or so that get added?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 it can be found at this location: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer

Comment: I am not familar with NuGet. Does it basically mean I should download these assemblies through NuGet and it will be up to me where to store them?

Comment: You add the NuGet package reference to you Visual Studio project and it will allow you to build against them  You can set the references to copy-local to copy them to your output directory.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.6.1 and VS 2017. Under my references. I have downloaded the NuGet package in your link, version 16.143.2. I see Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client & Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client in my project References. And I’ve added “using” directives for the same. However, I still get build messages saying, “Can’t find reference…” for both as well as “...TeamFoundation does not exist in namespace ‘Microsoft’”. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

We can find in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```