# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, client

My computer has Visual Studio 2013 installed.
I tried to compile some source code but it doesn't work.
It is C# language and it uses namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client

When I install VS2010, it compiles well!
I find that the source code use VS2010  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client's dll file.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application are trying to referencing dlls `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` from the GAC.

One solution is just as you done, install VS 2010 on the development environment and referencing the Microsoft.TeamFoundation dlls from the GAC. VS 2010 installed version 10 of the Team Foundation dlls into the development GAC.

However, this will cause you need to also install VS2010 on the build agent. A better solution is using **Nuget Package**. These have [been moved into a Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/).

> They're also stored under the "CommonExtensions" folder of your Visual
>   Studio installation, but these are not meant to be referenced anymore,
>   that's what the NuGet package is for.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1x.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

Take a look at this similar question: [Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll in Visual Studio 2015 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712197/where-can-i-find-microsoft-teamfoundation-versioncontrol-client-dll-in-visual-st)